# Are all distributions of the form $ \varphi \mapsto \int \varphi^{(n)} d\mu $?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Distributions are defined as the set of linear continuos operators over the set of test functions $ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) = C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}) $, i.e.
$ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})^* $.

My question is:

are all distributions of the form

$$ \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) \ni \varphi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi^{(n)}(x) d \mu (x) \in \mathbb{R} $$

(integral of differential operators against some measure) where $\varphi^{(n)}$ is the $n-$th derivative of $f$, and $\mu$ is a measure (or possibly linear combinations of such functionals)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the distribution $u$ has [finite order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640565/what-is-the-definition-of-the-order-of-a-distribution) (for instance, if it’s a tempered distribution) then yes: you can simply take $\mu=(-1)^n\partial_x^{-n}u$, recalling that taking [the antiderivative of any distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134545/is-there-a-distributional-antiderivative) is always a well-defined operation (although the antiderivative is only uniquely defined up to an additive constant). For $n$ large enough, $\mu$ will actually be (say) a continuous function on all $\mathbb R$ if $u$ has finite order.

If $u$ has infinite order, for instance if $u:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \partial_x^n\delta(x-n)$, then the above holds only locally in $x$, or you need to be allowed to take an infinite sum of functionals as you wrote above, where you have a non-zero contribution for every $n$. But also in this case, what you ask is morally true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, if $T$ (or $u$ in your notation, I guess) has finite order, then it is indeed a repeated (distributional) derivative of some function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (or $\mu$ in your notation - by the way: by taking the antiderivative will you indeed eventually reach a *continuous* $f$?).

Comment: As for the second example, the idea is that the order of $u$ increases on a larger an larger set, right? If indeed locally each distribution acts as a finite-order one, then this examples well captures the generality of your answer!

Comment: In what yiu wrote above, $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ in general, as distributions can grow arbitrarily fast at infinity. About your question: yes, because the antiderivative of a distribution of order $n$ has order $n-1$, and a distribution has order zero precisely when it is a locally integrable function. Then, if you take one more antiderivative, you get a continuous function (actually, the antiderivative of a locally integrable function is absolutely continuous). If you take even more antiderivatives, you obtain a $C^k$ function for any finite $k$

Comment: Yes, any distribution locally has finite order, and the “only” bad thing that can happen is that you get a larger and larger order by taking a larger compact set. You cannot do a similar example to what I wrote above by summing derivatives of arbitrary order of Dirac deltas on a compact set: what you would obtain cannot be a distribution. That is why I chose the deltas to be supported at $x=n$, so their support escapes to infinity as the order of the derivation grows.

Comment: Very interesting. So, if $\{ q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an enumeration of rationals in $K=[0,1]$, then $ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \partial^n \delta (x-q_n)$ is not a distribution because it doesn't even act linearly on test functions.

Comment: Well, it acts linearly at least formally, but it does not have finite order on $K$, so it cannot be a distribution. And I am pretty sure that thing is not well-defined for most test functions (actually, I am not even sure how to construct a test function supported in $K$ such that the above sum **is** well-defined and finite)